Integrating Google Cloud Spanner with Spring Data JPA
I'm migrating my springboot app from cloud SQL (PostgresSQL) to Cloud Spanner and will be using Google SQL dialect for spanner interaction. During this migration, i am facing the below error.
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionImpl.<clinit>(ConnectionImpl.java:135)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionOptions.getConnection(ConnectionOptions.java:1073)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.AbstractJdbcConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbcConnection.java:65)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:56)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcDriver.connect(JdbcDriver.java:196)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: INTERNAL: Could not instantiate statement parser for dialect GOOGLE_STANDARD_SQL
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerExceptionPreformatted(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:319)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerExceptionPreformatted(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:325)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.AbstractStatementParser.getInstance(AbstractStatementParser.java:93)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.AbstractStatementParser.<clinit>(AbstractStatementParser.java:145)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.AbstractStatementParser.getInstance(AbstractStatementParser.java:91)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ClientSideStatementImpl$CompileException: Could not compile statement SHOW VARIABLE AUTOCOMMIT
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ClientSideStatementImpl.compile(ClientSideStatementImpl.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ClientSideStatements.getCompiledStatements(ClientSideStatements.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.SpannerStatementParser.<init>(SpannerStatementParser.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ClientSideStatementImpl.compile(ClientSideStatementImpl.java:156)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/spanner/v1/DirectedReadOptions
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2846)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ClientSideStatementNoParamExecutor.<init>(ClientSideStatementNoParamExecutor.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.spanner.v1.DirectedReadOptions
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 70 common frames omitted


My App uses Spring 3, Java 17 and latest hibernate and JPA libraries. Below Dependencies are added for spanner. I was able to run a simple app with same dependencies successfully.
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner-hibernate-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner</artifactId>
            <version>6.80.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>


The problem is probably caused due to a dependency conflict in your project. You seem to be adding both google-cloud-spanner and google-cloud-spanner-jdbc. However, google-cloud-spanner is a transitive dependency of google-cloud-spanner-jdbc, so that should not really be necessary.
Also, the version of the Spanner JDBC driver that you are adding (2.8.0) is 2 years old, while the version of google-cloud-spanner is from a couple of weeks back. The combination of these two are probably causing your issues.
I would recommend that you take this sample application as a starting point, especially for the dependencies, and try to work from there: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate/tree/master/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate-samples/spring-data-jpa-full-sample
Or otherwise, try to simplify your dependencies to the following:
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Dialect and JDBC Driver dependencies-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner-hibernate-dialect</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


Thank you for the suggestion. Your directions helped me solve the issue. The actual solution was to upgrade all the dependencies that uses grpc internally. If we are using any google services like bigquery etc, those needs to be updated as well
